# newbie question memory and code optimisation

Tags: iphone, objective-c

this is what i write

```
domaine *detailsDomaine = [search_result objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[detailsDomaine valueForKey:@"nom"]];
```

Is it possible to not assign a variable (detailsDomaine)to reach the same result ?
Do i have to release detailsDomaine variable after that ?

I'm not using it anywhere else in the rest of the code...

Comment: I'd say this is actually better than cramming the "[search_result objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]" in the label assignment line. It's much more readable and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible not to create separate variable for this. Replace `detailsDomaine` in second row with your right side of assignment in first row:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[search_result objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"nom"]];
```

And no, you don't have to release the `detailsDomaine` object afterwards since you did not `retain` it.

Comment: @krifur If it would be reatained with property then it needs to be nil not release,and if you have allocated it then you can release it and also make it nil after that.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to release detailsDomaine because you did not allocate any memory for it or retain it. You could do something like this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[search_result objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"nom"]];
```

but it's rather ugly.

Answer (score 0):

first of all You do not need to release it ...

you can write it also in a single statement like

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[search_result objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"nom"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct, let me just add this: What Johnny Grass said is true. It's ugly, i.e. harder to read. It also won't gain you anything. The compiler will probably note the excess assignment, and optimize it out. And even if it does, unless this is going to be called 10,000 times in a second, it's not worth optimizing it.